# Where do you store your library of PowerShell scripts?

Tags: powershell, scripting

As soon as you start using PowerShell, you are likely to start collecting small, useful scripts. Managing them well is tricky.

- Where do you keep your PowerShell scripts?
- How do you track versions & do backups?
- How do you synchronize between machines?
- How do you integrate new versions of other's scripts?  (Including dealing with breaking changes between their scripts and yours)
- Do you see PowerShell V2 changing the picture?

Comment: This should be made a community wiki, methinks.

Answer (score 2):

We treat PowerShell scripts just like other code.  They are stored in TFS just like everything else.  This handles storage, backups, versioning, and merging.  Our standard build & deployment process handles moving these scripts between servers.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for source control.  Our project's powershell scripts usually wind up in one of:

- $/project/Trunk/Build
- $/project/Trunk/Tests/Bin
- $/project/Trunk/Tools/Bin

For personal scripts, at the moment I use two approaches.  First I create a ~\Bin, put that in the path and put my personal PowerShell scripts there.  The second approach is that I use Live Mesh to sync a PowerShell folder between all my machines.  It has scripts, presentations, etc in it.s  I should probably create a Bin subdir in the mesh folder and put that bin dir in my path.

V2 introduces Module support, so any modules I create would go under ~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules.

Regarding the question about using scripts from others and versioning, read up on Modules and [Module Manifests](http://www.bing.com/search?q=PowerShell+module+manifest&form=IE8SRC&src=IE-SearchBox) in V2.  I think this new feature will help.

Answer (score 1):

I keep my powershell profile & custom scripts in a [mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/) repository. I frequently switch between my development machine at home and the development environment at work so using a distributed VCS really has its advantages: Each machine is self-contained (no need to access a source-control-server at work from home through a VPN that does not exist in my case).

I pull/push changes from the local repo on each machine to a "transfer" repo on USB stick and things still work out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I put everything into source code control including my ever expanding powershell library.  This the primary way I version and spread the scripts amongst machines.